How can I extend the Locator class to implement my own custom Locator?
I have a reoccuring element I'd like to build a custom Locator API for. How can I extend the Locator class? It seems like I can only import the interface and implement it. I don't want rewrite that whole class, I just want to extend it for a few unique methods and flows. How do I import and inherit from the actual class ?
Example of what I'd like:
class CustomElement extends Locator {

 constructor(frame: Frame, selector: string, options?: LocatorOptions){

 super(...args);
 }
 openSearchDialog(){}
}

Edit:
Context => My product has a heavily reoccurring custom field web element. I want a class to build methods for interacting with this sort of field on top of what Playwright has. Also, as a way of self documenting it's distinction from other Locator objects.

Can you describe your exact use case and provide full context for why you want to do this? I've used Playwright extensively and have never felt the need to do this, so I doubt you'll need to extend a locator to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve. Please don't repeat the same paragraph twice to circumvent our question filter. Instead, add details. Thanks.

After your edit (thanks), can you show an example of the component and how you're currently selecting it with Playwright (maybe show a test or two), to motivate the exact issue you're experiencing?

@ggorlen The problem I'm trying to solve is how I go about extending the Locator class. There is no issue I'm experiencing, I really just want to extend the Locator class.

Extending the locator class is problem Y (your rather unusual attempted solution), not problem X (your original problem). There is probably a better way to achieve whatever issue X you're having, and Y is probably not necessary, as I explained before. Extending Locator is not really a thing. If you google it, this question shows up on the first page. If there's no issue X you're experiencing, then you don't need to extend locator--just use the normal locator API like every other Playwright test.

"I want a class to build methods for interacting with this sort of field on top of what Playwright has" -- I hope you are using a POM already, yes? This is the fundamental mechanism of abstraction for locators and higher-level methods that operate on a page.

@ggorlen there is no problem Y. I just want to extend the Locator class and build off it for the framework I'm building. You're trying quite hard to convince me I don't know what I want and I don't understand why. Please just take my question at face-value. How does one extend the Locator class in Playwright?

As mentioned, the API doesn't support extending locators. Extending locators is not a thing. So you're entering into undocumented, hacky territory to try to do a thing that nobody else does, and you won't provide context as to why you're even doing this in the first place. Sorry, but there has to be a better way. These problems usually have a very simple and elegant solution--interacting with a complex element is exactly what POMs and the basic locator API are perfectly designed for.

So I can't give you what you're asking for, because it's a nonexistent, unprecedented pattern, and I can't give a better option because you haven't explained the problem or shown your existing tests. Not a useful or answerable question in its current form, and needs full context to be answerable. Likely a textbook XY problem, as mentioned above (if it's not an XY problem, that's fine, but the key to defeating my comments is to show motivation for the pattern you're asking for, so either way, context is necessary).

I've explained the problem 3x. I've explained why I'd like to do so 3x. I've explicitly told you there is no larger problem or obstacle. It's just something I want to experiment with. How is "how to extend this class" not an answerable question? I've given an example of what I'd like to achieve, the problem I'd like to solve. How does this work for you? If you don't have an answer to the question asked, do you always assume the author must be asking the wrong question?

I've explained you that the Locator class is not intended to be subclassed by the user. There's nothing in the docs that suggests you should do this. Go ahead and try but it's a pointless exercise as far as I can tell, and there are perfectly straightforward, documented, existing solutions to abstracting things in Playwright. If someone gives you an answer, best not to use it, because it'll be a hack that will make your tests confusing to anyone else who uses Playwright, at best, and result in surprising bugs at worst.

I asked ChatGPT your question just now, and even though it tries really hard to accomodate XY problems even when it shouldn't, it also identifies this as such: "Extending the Locator class in Playwright directly is not straightforward because Playwright does not export the Locator class for extension." So there's your answer. If you don't believe me, that's fine, you can wait for someone else to come along and say the same thing.

Here's the ChatGPT thread. It's suggesting a wrapper, which is basically like a POM, except for a single locator rather than a page. Perfectly fine solution. I then insist on subclassing and it shows a possible approach but disclaims "This approach is fragile and should be used with caution. Playwright's internal APIs are not guaranteed to be stable and might change without notice. If you decide to use this in a production environment, be prepared for potential maintenance challenges when upgrading Playwright."

Don't. This isn't supported by Playwright in any capacity since the Locator class is not exported (only the type). You'd have to dig into Playwright internals and pull in a version-specific private class in order to extend it.
The correct approach for abstractions in Playwright are POMs for pages, and traditional wrapper classes with methods that operate on a locator at a higher-level, among other approaches. You can also use plain functions for one-off functionality. See Playwright: how to create a static utility method? for a variety of good (and a few discouraged) options for writing Playwright abstractions other than POMs and class wrappers.
There's not much context for your class or actual use case, but here's how you'd normally write this with a higher-order class using composition, not inheritance:
import {Frame, Locator} from "playwright";

class CustomLocator {
  constructor(frame: Frame, selector: string, options?: LocatorOptions) {
    this.dialog = frame.locator(selector, options);
    // other locators
  }

  async openSearchDialog() {
    await this.dialog.click();
    // more actions to open a dialog
  }

  // more action methods
}

module.exports = CustomLocator;

Usage:
import {CustomLocator} from "./custom-locator";

const cl = new CustomLocator(frame, "div");
await cl.openSearchDialog();

I'm not sure what use this exact abstraction would be, but hopefully it communicates the idea and can be modified to fit whatever your actual needs are.
Generally speaking, much of the JS ecosystem (and maybe the wider programming world?) has moved away from inheritance, so it's not all that common to see it offered by modern library APIs. To pick a random example, React works by composition, not inheritance.
There's no space here for a deep dive, but you can start exploring the tradeoff with Prefer composition over inheritance?.

DVers, care to suggest an alternative? What's the issue here? The answer is correct as far as I can tell--subclassing Locator is simply not supported.
